# How to install Calibri font so it works on Linux?

Tags: fonts, xetex, linux

Im on Linux (POP OS 20.10). My document with Calibri doesn't compile:

```tex
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Could not map source abbreviation C for Calibri.
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Need to update /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/map/fontname/special.map?
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input Calibri
This is METAFONT, Version 2.7182818 (TeX Live 2020/Debian) (preloaded base=mf)


kpathsea: Running mktexmf Calibri
! I can't find file `Calibri'.
<*> ...jfour; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input Calibri
                                                  
Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...jfour; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input Calibri
                                                  
Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: Calibri.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input Calibri' failed to make Calibri.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.


! Package fontspec Error: The font "Calibri" cannot be found.
```

Is it possible to make it work?

Comment: Calibri is normally not licenced for use off Windows but you can use google chromeos carlito font which has identical metrics

Comment: texlive has a `carlito.sty` that sets this up for xetex/luatex and pdftex

Comment: the problem is that a person with which I collaborate (thru github) on that document started using Calibri in it. Im the maintainer so I can do whatever I want anyway.. Is there a good font that will work on both Windows and Linux to which I can change it?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have no idea how to use it

Comment: `\usepackage{carlito}`  might be all you need

Comment: I get the same error

Comment: You have not shown any code which makes it hard for anyone to help, but if you remove references to calibri and replace them with carlito then you cannot possibly get the same error that  calibri is not found.